# How to add new stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm really confused. Normally i use array push to add new data to a array. But it doesnt work atm. Can someone help me?

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Knijn zijn
        [artist] => Bertie Lukano
        [url] => http://www.last.fm/music/Bertie+Lukano/_/Knijn+zijn
        [streamable] => stdClass Object
            (
                [text] => 0
                [fulltrack] => 0
            )

        [listeners] => 1
        [mbid] => 
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => knijnzijn
        [artist] => Bertie Lukano
        [url] => http://www.last.fm/music/Bertie+Lukano/_/knijnzijn
        [streamable] => stdClass Object
            (
                [text] => 0
                [fulltrack] => 0
            )

        [listeners] => 1
        [mbid] => 
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Wij Vieren Feest
        [artist] => Bertie Lukano
        [url] => http://www.last.fm/music/Bertie+Lukano/_/Wij+Vieren+Feest
        [streamable] => stdClass Object
            (
                [text] => 0
                [fulltrack] => 0
            )

        [listeners] => 1
        [mbid] => 
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Hieper de piep ik heb de mexicaanse griep!
        [artist] => Bertie Lukano
        [url] => http://www.last.fm/music/Bertie+Lukano/_/Hieper+de+piep+ik+heb+de+mexicaanse+griep!
        [streamable] => stdClass Object
            (
                [text] => 0
                [fulltrack] => 0
            )

        [listeners] => 1
        [mbid] => 
    )

)
```

So i need to add a new stdClass Object but i cant figure out how.

```
[4] => stdClass Object
(
    [name] => name
    [artist] => artist
    [url] => url
    [streamable] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text] => 0
            [fulltrack] => 0
        )

    [listeners] => 1
    [mbid] => 
)
```

As you see inside the object need to be another object at [streamable] so i really dont know how to do that so i hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you include the code where you're not able to use `push`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid at all costs mixing objects within arrays to save yourself the headache later.

Usually this is how they're added:

```
$oData = new stdClass;
$oData->name  = 'Bob';
$oData->email = 'Bob@bob.com';
$aArray = array();
$aArray[] = $oData;
var_dump( $aArray );
```